# Why are the controller actions in Phoenix passed as atoms instead of functions?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
defmodule HelloWeb.Router do
  use HelloWeb, :router

  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    get("/", PageController, :index)
  end
end
```

In this example, why isn't the controller's function passed directly, like `get("/", PageController.index)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two reasons for this. The first is in how the module name becomes known. In your example, you have a scope for `HelloWeb`, and then a get endpoint in `PageController`. This actually calls the `HelloWeb.PageController` module.

The second reason, which I think is more important here, is because the function is not actually called directly. When you `use HelloWeb, :controller`, it defines an [`action/2`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/controller/pipeline.ex#L33-L35) function for you in your module. This `action/2` function is what gets called. It just calls the function that you specified.

This may seem like it is needlessly complex. But it allows us to define your own `action/2` function within your module to override the one provided by phoenix. Maybe all of the actions within a given module need some record(s) pulled from a database. This is where you could do that and put it within the assigns of the connection.

Comment: thank you, i also asked in https://elixirforum.com/t/why-the-paths-in-phoenix-require-an-atom-instead-of-a-function/20341 just for reference